How can i check that exception was thrown and handled in Junit4/Mockito?
I'm writing tests using Junit4 and mockito and wondering if there is a possibility to check if specific exception was thrown and handled inside tested method.
What I mean is - I have for example following simple method:
public int someMethodAsInt(String key, int defaultValue) {
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(someMethod(key, String.valueOf(defaultValue)));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return defaultValue;
    }
}

I know that i can make test like that:
int result = myService.someMethodAsInt("key", 123);
assertEquals(123, result);

I just wonder if there is a way to check that the exception was thrown and caught inside the tested method. I can use only Junit4 or Mockito, I know that there are some other extensions, but we don't use them in project.

An exception being thrown and caught is an implementation detail which you shouldn't test. As long as your method behaves as expected (i.e. returns the expected value for a given input), you should be good. Why do you care if an exception was involved in computing the value?

Just curiosity if it's possible. I know that if we get what we expect we shouldn't care about the exception inside.
